# Unable to stop, kill or remove Docker container

Tags: docker

I've got a container running for 5 weeks now which I can neither stop nor kill nor remove. `docker ps` shows this (both containers cannot be removed actually):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
431a850b384f        f99983306232        "cmd /c 'start /B C:…"   5 weeks ago         Up 5 weeks          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   dockercompose18429431017078490850_xxx_1
e31f0b74a8cb        50eef858d93d        "cmd /c 'start /B C:…"   6 weeks ago         Up 6 weeks          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   dockercompose15856640072218908353_xxx_1
```

`docker stop e31` and `docker kill e31` just hung up and do nothing. `docker rm e31` shows error:

```
Error response from daemon: removal of container e31 is already in progress
```

If I run `docker inspect e31` I see the container is running, it's not dead:

```
    "Id": "e31f0b74a8cb8225d5104f8de7e1c583ed1852133ad2870015017b09d3df8dfa",
    "Created": "2019-05-08T06:57:24.3143863Z",
    ...
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1324,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-05-08T06:57:30.3396878Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
  ...
```

How to get rid of it?

System info:

- Server Version: 19.03.0-rc2
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.175)

Comment: Can you add the output of the command `docker ps`? Also how are you calling the commands above? Post an example

Comment: No way to resolve this issue also with the last engine version: I upgraded on my Win2019 server the docker engine to version 19.03.5 but still unable to stop/remove a container...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have also encountered this a few times.  What I did to stop the 'hung' container was -

1. `docker ps` to display container ID
2. `net stop docker` - stop docker engine (Note all containers will stop)
3. Delete folder in `c:\programdata\docker\containers` whose name starts with the ID from step 1
4. `net start docker` - start docker engine

Unfortunately the docker service still has to be stopped and started but at least I didn't have to re-install.

Answer (score 8):

For urgent cases, when even `docker rm -f` is does not help, it can be solved by stopping deamon and manually removing container:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/<CONTAINER_ID>
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: I get the following error when removing files under `/var/lib/docker/containers/<CONTAINER_ID>`.

`rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_ID>/mounts/shm': Device or resource busy`

Answer (score 2):

For us it was an update that changed the `docker.service` config on RHEL.

**Solution**

```sh
docker rm -f <container-id>
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart containerd
systemctl restart docker
docker-compose up -d
```

**The Error we were receiving**

````sh
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
Recreating 952ba6a5bbc4_my-app ... error
t: connection refused: unknown'
​
ERROR: for 952ba6a5bbc4_my-app  Cannot start service my-app: b'dial unix \x00/run/containerd/s/086e56: connect: connection refused: unknown'
​
ERROR: for my-app  Cannot start service my-app: b'dial unix \x00/run/containerd/s/086e56: connect: connection refused: unknown'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.```
````

Comment: Only response which worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That may sound too radical but I've just reinstalled Docker. The redundant containers have gone. Finally.

Comment: as I mentioned, the containers were running for numerous weeks. The laptop has rebooted dozens of times.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem multiple times. `Error response from daemon: removal of container docker_container_id_goes_here is already in progress`

Restart your docker and run the following command in your powershell or terminal 
`docker rm docker_container_id_goes_here`

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker system prune`  to clean docker and then stop or remove your container.

Answer (score 0):

Twice in my experience the issue was due to the docker compose which produced a zombie process. The process name was `docker compose up`. Find the zombie with `htop` and kill its parent

Answer (score -2):

You kill a container by it's name, from the output on the OP the right command should be:

```
docker kill dockercompose15856640072218908353_xxx_1
```

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/) for more info. Give it a try and let me know if it worked

Comment: same as killing by id. Command line shows no result until cancelled. Container is still here.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a `docker` or `docker-compose` stack so I would try also `docker-compose kill|down` but before change the directory to whatever the Dockerfile is

Comment: Can you try restarting your docker service? It will stop all the containers you have running.

Comment: I restarted my laptop numerous times during last weeks. Even upgraded windows to 1903. No diff.

Answer (score -3):

Well try the below two commands, First stop the container and then remove it if they are from created using the Dockerfile.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

For docker-compose thing use this command to remove the attached containers

```
docker-compose down
```

Comment: tried both variants. `docker-compose down`, `docker-compose kill` did not help

Comment: did you try to restart or off/on the docker?

Comment: @FarrukhFaizy, it worked for me! Don't ask me why. However, it's not a viable solution :(